# Python - Insert 300 variables into SQLite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, insert, bulkinsert

I am receiving 300 values from heat sensor every minute. These 300 values needs to be inserted, as they are received every minute, into SQLite database.

I have created 302 rows in SQLite database with the first column being `S_ID` and second column being `timestamp`. Here, `S_ID` is being auto-incremented each time a row is added and the default value of `timestamp` column is the current system time. I have programmed such that I receive 300 heat sensor values every minute, put all 300 values in a list named `data` and insert `data` into database. Now, I need to know how I can write `executemany` statement without writing all 300 column names and `?` below.

```
data = [(300, 2, 4, ..., 5.5)] #these are 300 values that are inserted into a list when received from heat sensor
c.executemany('INSERT INTO heat_table (col3, col4, ..., col302) VALUES (?, ?, ..., ?)', data)
```

Comment: Best practice is to always explicitly list out the columns involved in an insert.  While there _might_ be a way to do this without naming columns, it could break if your table structure were ever to change.

Comment: Write code that creates the insert query instead of typing it out by hand.

Comment: Or use a database design that doesn't need 300 columns. Something with one row per sensor per minute?

Comment: Usually you would write one **row** per sensor value instead of having 300 **columns** in your database.

Comment: What are the actual names of your columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create these names with list comprehensions and then join them:

```
query = ('INSERT INTO heat_table (' +
         ', '.join('col%d' % i for i in range(3, len(data) + 3)) +
         ') VALUES (' +
         ', '.join('?' * len(data)) +
         ')')
```